# How to install Angular IDE in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu-16.04

I am angular2 beginner. I am try to install angular IDE in my won system but it does not install.

Command : -

```
npm install -g angular-ide
```

error:-

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/angular-ide/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-ide"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/angular-ide/bin/ngide
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/angular-ide/bin/ngide' -> '/usr/bin/ngide'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/angular-ide/bin/ngide' -> '/usr/bin/ngide'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/angular-ide/bin/ngide',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/bin/ngide' }

npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/iron/.npm/_logs/2017-05-01T03_32_46_250Z-debug.log
```

Please tell us how to install angular IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo npm install -g angular-ide
```

Its says access problem , so try this .

Comment: How to oepn folder if install ngide?

Comment: I dont use ngIDE , but use other ids , I guess this should be running same way .  start ngIDE , then from the menu do File->Open->select your folder

Answer (score 1):

```
step 1:

 cd /home/user/Downloads

step 2: 
   
   chmod +x angularide-ci-2020.7.22-offline-installer-linux.run 

step 3:

  ./angularide-ci-2020.7.22-offline-installer-linux.run 

step 4: 
   it will launch the widget

step 5: 
    Follow the instructions

step 6: 

   Done
```